# Синонимизировать [edge] и [microsoft-edge]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

У нас по метке [edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) всего 6 вопросов и метка в них используется как [microsoft-edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge). Оригинальное описание метки сейчас говорит, что метка предназначена для вопросов про 2G мобильный интернет, но я сильно не уверен в необходимости такого рода метки. Тем более, что 2G мобильный интернет уже почти никому не нужен.

Comment: в 6 вопросах по моему проще метку исправить на второй вариант, чем плодить не совсем очевидный синоним. а саму метку удалить, коли по ней и вопросов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Просто исправляйте, если увидите, метку на [microsoft-edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge), где надо. Синонимизировать не надо. Её всё равно почти никто не использует. Если не будет использоваться совсем, автоматически удалится со временем.

Comment: Учитывая малое кол-во вопросов и игнорирование этого вопроса модераторами, то так и приходится делать.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я метки на вопросах поменял с [tag:edge] на [tag:microsoft-edge]. Должна пропасть со временем. Из модераторов только Юрий вопросами меток интересуется.

Answer (score -2):

Предлагаю для [edge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) сделать синоним [2g](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2g), [3g](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3g) и [gprs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gprs) и объединить их под [gprs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gprs). Принципиально эти технологии схожи. В контексте программирования и системного администрирования не вспомню ни одного различия. С [lte](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lte) различия существенны.

Comment: А вы посмотрите как эта метка используется у нас или на enSO. В основном речь идёт про новый браузер от Microsoft, а не про мобильный интернет.

Comment: Если она будет меняться на обьединенную, то её перестануть использовать для браузера

Comment: Я считаю, что синонимы должны подбираться под наиболее частое использование людьми.

Comment: А я считаю что они для того чтоб схожие вопросы группировать

Comment: @eri, а как одно другому мешает?